# MySQL - query to get length of service in Years, months, days

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following query that I'm trying to get the length of service of a person at their company. The idea is to find how many years, months, and days they have served there.

For example:

**Todays date:** Jun 13, 2017.

**Exhibit A:** John Doe has served since Feb 10, 2016. So length of service should be 1 year, 4 months, 3 days excluding the end date.

**Exhibit B:** Jane Doe has served since 13th Jun, 2007. So length of service should be Or 10 years excluding the end date.

My Query *spoiler: it's not right*

```
    SELECT  `firstname` ,
            DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) ,  '%Y' ) - DATE_FORMAT( startdate,  '%Y' ) - ( DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) ,  '00-%m-%d' ) < DATE_FORMAT( startdate,  '00-%m-%d' ) ) AS years, 
            PERIOD_DIFF( DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) ,  '%Y%m' ) , DATE_FORMAT( startdate, '%Y%m' ) ) AS months, 
            DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , startdate ) AS days
    FROM users
```

It gives me the results in years, as well as months, as well as days. So for someone who has served a year it would output: 1 year, 12 months, 365 days etc.

Comment: Omrakhur, Did my solution work ?

Comment: What is the answer for Jan 31, 2016 to Mar 1, 2016?

Comment: And this one is a worse case; it wrecks all the algorithms I have thought of:  Jan 31, 2016 to Mar 30, 2016

Comment: @RickJames Neither of the answers are working. Which one are you referring to in the last comment above?

Comment: I was thinking about shifting by 1 month if the day-of-month was less/greater, then computing the years/months.  But then got stumped on computing the days.  Give me the answer for those date ranges, and maybe I will try again.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for calculating the duration.

```
SELECT CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2016-02-10', CURDATE()), ' Yrs ',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2016-02-10', CURDATE())%12, ' Mth ',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, ('2016-02-10' + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2016-02-10', 
CURDATE()) YEAR
+ INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2016-02-10', CURDATE())%12 MONTH), CURDATE()), ' 
Days') AS `Duration`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably missing something, but you may try:

```
set @d = '2017-06-13';
create table users
( user int not null primary key
, startdate date not null
);
insert into users (user, startdate) 
values (1, '2016-02-10'), (2, '2007-06-13');

SELECT  user 
     ,  startdate
     ,  DATE_FORMAT( @d ,  '%Y' ) - DATE_FORMAT( startdate,  '%Y' ) as y
     ,  DATE_FORMAT( @d ,  '%m' ) - DATE_FORMAT( startdate,  '%m' ) as m
     ,  DATE_FORMAT( @d ,  '%d' ) - DATE_FORMAT( startdate,  '%d' ) as d
FROM users;


user    startdate   y   m   d
1       2016-02-10  1   4   3
2       2007-06-13  10  0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible (not the best) solution to this:

```
SELECT firstname
     , startdate
     , CASE
           WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) < YEAR(startdate) THEN 0 #or some such validation
           ELSE YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(startdate)
       END years
     , CASE
           WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) < MONTH(startdate) THEN MONTH(startdate) - MONTH(CURDATE())
           ELSE MONTH(CURDATE()) - MONTH(startdate)
       END months
     , CASE
           WHEN DAY(CURDATE()) < DAY(startdate) THEN DAY(startdate) - DAY(CURDATE())
           ELSE DAY(CURDATE()) - DAY(startdate)
       END days
FROM users;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Select
TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, startdate, now() ) as _year
,TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, startdate, now() ) % 12 as _month
,FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, startdate, now() ) % 30.4375 ) as _day
FROM users
```

I tried it as, which gave me correct result:

```
Select
TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, '2016-02-10', now() ) as _year
,TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, '2016-02-10', now() ) % 12 as _month
,FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, '2016-02-10', now() ) % 30.4375 ) as _day
```